# undefined '+' method for selected count on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
poll_answers = PollAnswer.joins(:poll_answer_variant => {:poll_question => :poll}).select("count(poll_answers.user_id) as submits_count, poll_answers.poll_question_id").where("polls.id = 105").group("poll_questions.id, poll_answer_variants.id")

grouped = poll_answers.group_by(&:poll_question_id)

grouped[81].inject{|sum, answer_variant| sum += answer_variant.submits_count}
```

after what i get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for #<PollAnswer poll_question_id: 81, poll_answer_variant_id: 9>
from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemodel-3.2.7/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
from (irb):926:in `block in irb_binding'
from (irb):926:in `each'
from (irb):926:in `inject'
from (irb):926
from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

It must be because of my virtual select count is not described like a model attribute? How can i fix that? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Enumerable#inject` without arguments, your block will receive the first two elements the first iteration, then the result of the previous iteration and the third element, etc.

You can pass an argument to `#inject` to tell him to call your block with a value of your choice and the first element, then the result and the second, etc.

In your case (please notice that I use `+` and not `+=`) :

```
grouped[81].inject(0) do |sum, answer_variant|
  sum + answer_variant.submits_count
end
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject for more details about how to use `Enumerable#inject`.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs on [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):  "if you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then uses the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo."  So the first time through the loop, the value of sum is an PollAnswer object.   You need to initialize sum:

```
grouped[81].inject(0){|sum, answer_variant| sum += answer_variant.submits_count}
```